# HTTPS and ICMP Ingress Rules for SecurityGroup in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am trying to create cloudformation template for SecurityGroup. I am stuggling to see right details on documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html

Attached snapshot what i need to do:

[image]

Help needed to create this cloudformation template

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input, here's a sample.
Feel free to adjust the name and description as you see fit.

```yaml
SimpleSecurityGroup:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: "Sample description"
    GroupName: "Sample-SG"
    VpcId: 'INSERT_VPC_ID_HERE'
    SecurityGroupIngress: 
      - 
        CidrIp: '10.X.X.X/24'
        IpProtocol: "icmp"
      - 
        SourceSecurityGroupId: 'sg-xxxxxxx'
        IpProtocol: "tcp"
        FromPort: 443
        ToPort: 443
```

Please refer to the [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule-1.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-rule-sourcesecuritygroupid) documentation for additional details.